# Friendl_id record not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, friendly-id

I just add friendly_id to beautify my urls.

**i get an error**

```
      Couldn't find User with 'id'={:id=>"foo"}
```

Here is my setup

User.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord

 extend FriendlyId
 friendly_id :last_name, use: %i[slugged finders]
```

Users_controller.rb

```
def find_user
  @user = User.friendly.find(id: params[:id])
end
```

I added this to my user table

```
add_column :users, :slug,                   :string
add_index :users,  :slug,                   unique: true
```

And the CreateFriendlyIdSlugs table has been correctly generated

i'm very in trouble with this issue, i'v red all the documentation and i can't see where my code fail

thx for helping

Answer (score 2):

You can either use:

```
User.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

or

```
User.friendly.find_by(id: params[:id])
```

this #find_by can take hash as an input in case you are using hash params.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was how i call the params in my find

the answser is

```
@user = User.friendly.find(params[:id])
```

instead of

```
@user = User.friendly.find(id: params[:id])
```